# Subtract value from slice

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I want to subtract a value from a slice so that these rows are updated, however, the rows never change.

```
df
A B C
1 1 3
2 3 4
5 6 8
2 3 4

idx = 1
val = 2
df.iloc[idx:-1,0].sub(val)
```

Desired result:

```
A B C
1 1 3
0 3 4
3 6 8
0 3 4
```

I've tried the following as well

```
df.iloc[idx:-1,0] = df.iloc[idx:-1,0].sub(val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier with `-=`:

```
>>> df.iloc[idx:, 0] -= val
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  1  3
1  0  3  4
2  3  6  8
3  0  3  4
>>>
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're adding `-1` to the end of the slice, that would skip the last value, so to fix your code try:

```
df.iloc[idx:, 0] = df.iloc[idx:, 0].sub(val)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought -1 means to the end, but instead it leaves out the last. To check my values I used df.tail(1), which was the entry that didn't change, causing me to believe that nothing changed.